# No internet in one LAN after connecting a router via another LAN port of TPLINK Archer C20

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp

The parent is the TPLINK Archer C20, and it's connected to the ISP's ethernet. I got another router in another room, connected to the C20's LAN port. It by default works fine, has stable internet. My desktop is connected to the C20's LAN port but it does not have any internet connection. I put the DHCP settings below. What can I do so that both my LAN has internet connection?

DHCP Config of C20:
[image: DHCP Config of C20]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned that this was known as **Slave Router**. Everything works as expected by following the steps below:

1. Set up the parent router, in my case TPLINK Archer C20 and made sure it has internet connectivity, and importantly, `DHCP Server` enabled. Note down the current IP of this router, it should be something like **192.168.0.1** (for TPLINK).
2. Power on the slave router, login to the router's homepage, disable `DHCP Server` from LAN Setup page. Change current IP of this router, it has to be in the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Subnetworks) and different than the one found in the previous step. I had set it to **192.168.0.155** for my slave router.
3. Connect the slave to the parent's LAN port.
4. Restart the parent.

Now, any device connected to any of the slave or parent through either Wireless or LAN gets internet since the parent now manages the DHCP server only.